# Calling abstract classes' destructors

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I've got three classes.

```
class Son : public Father;

class Father : public Grandfather;
```

`Father` is abstract and so is `Grandfather`. `Son` is NOT abstract.

If I do this:

```
Son* son = new Son();
```

and then do this:

```
delete(son)
```

how do I make sure that the destructors of `Father` and `Grandfather` are called?

Comment: As long as they have virtual destructors, that will do fine.

Comment: @chris You don't even need that if you're deleting a pointer to the most derived class.

Comment: @KerrekSB, an instance of the class `Son`.

Comment: @l19 Hopefully it's one created like `Son* son = new Son;`, right?

Comment: @l19: In  that case your code doesn't even compile. You can only call `delete` on pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB, what? `son` is a pointer.

Comment: @l19: You just said it's an object instance. Which one is it to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructors of parent classes to your pointer will be called no matter what.

You should make the top level class's destructor `virtual` though, so you can delete a pointer to a `Grandfather` and ensure all the subclass's destructors are called as well. Not doing so leads to undefined behavior, which is always a bad thing.

Once a function is `virtual`, it will be virtual for the entire derivation tree, no need to mark it in child classes. However, it's usually good form to do so, it helps people reading the code.

Comment: If it's not virtual, the problem isn't that the destructors of derived types aren't called; it's that the behavior is undefined. The language definition does not tell you what happens when you do that.

Comment: @Collin It **IS** necessary to mark it virtual in subclasses in order for the method in that subclass to be virtual.

Comment: @user1610015 Um.. no. Quoth the standard: 10.3 paragraph 2: "If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly
from Base, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualiﬁcation, and refqualiﬁer (or absence of same) as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared)"